# GMT Time conversion in Java

Tags: java, android, datetime, jakarta-ee

I am trying to covert an  time to an specified standard format.

Time format which i am getting from an application `Wed May 11 13:18:48 PDT 2005`

Time format which i am trying to convert is  `2005-02-14T20:05:19Z`

I am able to do this in Java 8 but not in 7. I tried googling , but still dint get the solution. Is there any way to do this in Java 7 ?.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: THere is `SimpleDateFormat` in Java 7-; or you can do yourself a favour and use threetenbp or JodaTime ;) You won't be lost, since Java 8's API is largely inspired by Joda Time (threetenbp is a backport of JSR 310 by one of the Joda Time main authors, namely Stephen Colebourne)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert your time format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(yourDateObject));
```

Comment: bit tweeked in  your code and worked fine :)

`SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(""EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy"");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
String output = outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(input));`